# How do I programmatically open a MS Word document without invoking the Document_Open macro

Tags: ms-word, office-automation

I am trying to use Office Automation to open a word document.  The problem is that I would like to open it without invoking the Document_Open macro.  Is there a way to do this?

The relevant line below is wordApp.Documents.Open()

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class WordFunctions
  Public Shared Function ConvertToDoc(ByVal file As String) As Boolean
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application

    Try
        wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application", "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

    Try
        wordApp.Caption = "Automated Word Instance"
        wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=file, Visible:=False, ConfirmConversions:=False)

        wordDoc.SaveAs(FileName:=file + ".doc", FileFormat:=Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument)
        wordDoc.Activate()
        wordDoc.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        wordApp.Quit(SaveChanges:=False)
    End Try
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You should probably specify what version of word you're working with -- 2003 or 2007?

Answer (score 0):

If it's Word 2007 documents you're working with, try changing your code to work with the XML directly, instead of using the Office Automation API.

It's faster, and you don't have to worry about macros (and lots of other automation issues).